# Python shared property parent/child

Tags: python, python-2.7

Embarrassed to ask but I am using webapp2 and I am templating out a solution to make it easier to define routes[based on this google webapp2 route function](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/handlers.html). But it all depends on being able to define `TYPE_NAME` at the child level.  The idea is the parent sets everything up and the child just needs to implement the `_list` function.  The issue I ran into is `TYPE_NAME` is None and I need it to be the child.

```
#main WSGI is extended to have this function 
class WSGIApplication(webapp2.WSGIApplication):
    def route(self, *args, **kwargs):
        def wrapper(func):
            self.router.add(webapp2.Route(handler=func, *args, **kwargs))
            return func

        return wrapper
```

---

```
from main import application
class ParentHandler(RequestHandler):
    TYPE_NAME = None

    @application.route('/', name="list_%s" %TYPE_NAME)
    def list(self):
          return self._list()

class ChildHandler(ParentHandler):
    TYPE_NAME = 'child'

    def _list(self):
         return []
```

I have tried a couple solutions using "class properties" but they didn't pan out.  Open to other ideas, I basically just need the child class to inherit the decorated properties and execute them.

**Edit:**

For all of those on the edge of their seats wondering how I fix this,I was not able to get everything I needed out of the decorator so I ended up using a meta.  I also added a `_URLS` parameter to allow for adding additional "routes".  It maps  `custom` function to the route.  Really wanted to use a decorator but couldn't get it to work.

```
class RequestURLMeta(type):
    def __new__(mcs, name, bases, dct):
        result = super(RequestURLMeta, mcs).__new__(mcs, name, bases, dct)
        urls = getattr(result, '_URLS', {}) or {}
        for k,v in urls.iteritems():
            template = v.pop('template')
            app.route(getattr(result, k), template, **v)

        if getattr(result, 'TYPE_NAME', None):
            app.route(result.list, result.ROOT_PATH, methods=['GET'],name="%s" % result.TYPE_NAME)
        #other ones went here..

    return result

class ParentHandler(RequestHandler):
    __metaclass__ = RequestURLMeta


class ChildHandler(ParentHandler):
    TYPE_NAME = 'child'
    _URLS = { 'custom': '/custom', 'TYPE_NAME': 'custom_test' }
    def _list(self):
        return []
    def custom(self):  pass
```

Comment: What is the `application.route()` call doing?  Is this where you want the `TYPE_NAME` defined in the child to be used?

Comment: @F.J I upated the post added the route function and updated the decorator to be more descriptive.

Comment: Oh so is that a decorator for the `list()` function?  If so it should be `@application.route(...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think to get this to work you are going to need to use a [metaclass](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6581949/505154).  It might look something like the following (untested):

```
from main import application

class RouteMeta(type):
    def __new__(mcs, name, bases, dct):
        type_name = dct.get("TYPE_NAME")
        if type_name is not None:
            @application.route('/', type_name)
            def list(self):
                return self._list()
            dct["list"] = list
        return super(RouteMeta, mcs).__new__(mcs, name, bases, dct)

class ParentHandler(RequestHandler):
    __metaclass__ = RouteMeta

class ChildHandler(ParentHandler):
    TYPE_NAME = 'child'

    def _list(self):
         return []
```

Instead of having the `list()` method an attribute of `ParentHandler`, it is dynamically created for classes that inherit from `ParentHandler` and have `TYPE_NAME` defined.

If `RequestHandler` also uses a custom metaclass, have `RouteMeta` inherit from `RequestHandler.__metaclass__` instead of `type`.

Comment: I was able to take this and work with it... the big thing was instead of doing the `type_name = ` code before the `super` call I took the result of the `super` call and just patched it there.  I posted a dumbed down example above.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
@application.route('/', name="list_%s" %TYPE_NAME)
def list(self):*emphasized text*
    ...
```

is semantically identical to this one:

```
def list(self):
    ...
list = application.route('/', name="list_%s" %TYPE_NAME)(list)
```

i.e. the method `route` is called inside the `ParentHandler` scope and
whatever lazy method you try, it will not work. You should try something
different:

```
from main import application

def route_list(klass):
    klass.list = application.route('/',
        name="list_%s" % klass.TYPE_NAME)(klass.list)
    return klass

class ParentHandler(RequestHandler):

    def list(self):
          return self._list()

class ChildHandler(ParentHandler):
    TYPE_NAME = 'child'

    def _list(self):
         return []

# in python3 would be:
# @route_list
# class ChildHandler(ParentHandler):
#   ...
ChildHandler = route_list(ChildHandler)
```

Comment: This is actually what I was leaning to... a class decorator to set all of the routes up.  do they only work python3x ?